# No me aparecen proyectos en visual studio community 2022

Tags: c#, web, razor

Estoy creando proyectos con razor o webassembly sin embargo no me aparece ningun proyecto a la hora de crearlo y solo me pasa con esas plantillas

[image: Imagen de apoyo]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el contenido de ese archivo .sln? Ve a path de la solucion y abre el WebApplication1.sln con un editor de texto (cualquiera, como el block de notas, etc), y comparte el contenido completo. Porque asi como estas parece que no tiene ningun proyecto dicha solucion.

Comment: Ahí ya modifiqué la pregunta con la imagen que me pediste

Comment: Camilo. En ese archivo .sln no tienes ningun proyecto "referenciado". Deberias agregarlo al proyecto que tu comentas que generaste. Click derecho en la solucion y agregar "Proyecto existente"

Comment: Ya lo he intentado sin embargo no me deja añadir nada lo raro es que las carpetas son creadas sin embargo no las reconoce

Answer (score 0):

Camilo.

Podrías intentar lo siguiente:

1. Primero debes tener cerrado el VS2022.
2. Lo siguiente es ir al instalador de VS2022(VS Installer).
3. Ubicar la versión de VS e ir al apartado "modificar".
4. Aparecerá una ventana con todos los componentes que tienes
   instalados llamado "Cargas de trabajo".
5. Ahora dirígete a la pestaña "Componentes Individuales".
6. En el buscador escribe el nombre del componente "WebAssembly" y
   selecciona o marca las que coincidan.
7. Finalmente haz clic en modificar (en la parte inferior derecha de
   la ventana).
8. Luego de finalizar vuelve a abrir VS2022.

Espero que esto solucione el problema, suerte.